# MongoDB Rust Driver weird behavior

Tags: mongodb, rust

There is this weird thing,
I have installed the MongoDB Compass and made a aggregation query that works in the Aggregation tab but now when I use the same query in my rust web server it behaves very weirdly

Original message:

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"61efd41c56ffe6b1b4a15c7a"},"time":{"$date":"2022-01-25T10:42:36.175Z"},"edited_time":{"$date":"2022-01-30T14:29:54.361Z"},"changes":[],"content":"LORA","author":{"$oid":"61df3cab3087579f8767a38d"}}
```

Message in MongoDB compass after the query:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61efd41c56ffe6b1b4a15c7a"
    },
    "time": {
        "$date": "2022-01-25T10:42:36.175Z"
    },
    "edited_time": {
        "$date": "2021-12-17T09:55:45.856Z"
    },
    "changes": [{
        "time": {
            "$date": "2021-12-17T09:55:45.856Z"
        },
        "change": {
            "ChangedContent": "LORA"
        }
    }],
    "content": "LMAO",
    "author": {
        "$oid": "61df3cab3087579f8767a38d"
    }
}
```

Message after the Web Servers query:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61efd41c56ffe6b1b4a15c7a"
    },
    "time": {
        "$date": "2022-01-25T10:42:36.175Z"
    },
    "edited_time": {
        "$date": "2022-01-30T14:40:57.152Z"
    },
    "changes": {
        "$concatArrays": ["$changes", [{
            "time": {
                "$date": "2022-01-30T14:40:57.152Z"
            },
            "change": {
                "ChangedContent": "$content"
            }
        }]]
    },
    "content": "LMAO",
    "author": {
        "$oid": "61df3cab3087579f8767a38d"
    }
}
```

Pure query in MongoDB Compass:
$set stage

```json
{
  "changes": { $concatArrays: [ "$changes",  [ { "time": ISODate('2021-12-17T09:55:45.856+00:00'), "change": { "ChangedContent": "$content" } } ] ] },
  "edited_time": ISODate('2021-12-17T09:55:45.856+00:00'),
  "content": "LMAO",
}
```

Pure query in Web Server:

```rust
    let update_doc = doc! {
        "$set": {
            "changes": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                    "$changes", [
                        {
                            "time": now,
                            "change": {
                                "ChangedContent": "$content"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "edited_time": now,
            "content": content
        }
    };
```

I am using update_one method,
like this

```rust
 messages.update_one(message_filter, update_doc, None).await?;
```

I don't really understand, and this happens often, sometimes it fixes it self when I add somewhere randomly some scope in the doc eg.: { } but this time I couldn't figure it out,
I had version of the query with $push but that didn't work too
Is there some fault in the rust driver or am I doing something wrong, are there some rules about formatting when using rust driver that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set) aggregation pipeline stage is different from the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator. And the only difference that I can tell, is the pipeline stage handles `$concatArrays` while the update operator does not.

#### `$set` Aggregation Pipeline Stage

> `$set` appends new fields to existing documents. You can include one or more `$set` stages in an aggregation operation.
>
> To add field or fields to embedded documents (including documents in arrays) use the dot notation.
>
> To add an element to an existing array field with `$set`, use with `$concatArrays`.

#### `$set` Update Operator

> Starting in MongoDB 5.0, update operators process document fields with
> string-based names in lexicographic order. Fields with numeric names
> are processed in numeric order.
>
> If the field does not exist, `$set` will add a new field with the
> specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
> constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field,
> `$set` will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the
> dotted path to the field.
>
> If you specify multiple field-value pairs, `$set` will update or create
> each field.

So if you want to update an existing document by inserting elements into an array field, use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update operator (potentially with [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) if you're inserting multiple elements):

```rust
let update_doc = doc! {
    "$set": {
        "edited_time": now,
        "content": content
    },
    "$push": {
        "changes": {
            "time": now,
            "change": {
                "ChangedContent": "$content"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

**Edit:** I missed that `$content` was supposed to be mapped from the existing field as well. That is not supported by an update document, however MongoDB has support for using an aggregation pipeline to update the document. See: [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) So you can use the original `$set` just in a different way:

```rust
let update_pipeline = vec![
    doc! {
        "$set": {
            "changes": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                    "$changes", [
                        {
                            "time": now,
                            "change": {
                                "ChangedContent": "$content"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "edited_time": now,
            "content": content
        }
    }
];

messages.update_one(message_filter, update_pipeline, None).await?;
```

Comment: That does push a Object into that array but the ChangedContent has no value of field "content" from the message, may I ask why is that?

The result:
```json
{
    "changes": [{
        "time": {
            "$date": "2022-01-31T14:35:31.019Z"
        },
        "change": {
            "ChangedContent": "$content"
        }
    }],
    "content": "Loekrkkak",
}
```

Comment: @ArisaSnowbell my apologies, I've updated my answer

Comment: Oh, adding the doc in a vector changes it to a aggregation pipeline behavior, I had no idea, thank you so so so much, without you I wouldn't ever find that out.
It works perfectly now, thank you so so very much  you are amazing